# XSLT: Removing xmlns=""

Tags: xml, xslt, msbuild

I am transforming my service configuration files of the cloud project.
I don't have much knowledge about XML namespaces.
I am using MSBuild to execute XslTransformation task.
I am getting an unwanted xmlns="". How can I remove this from the output?

Thanks in Advance!

XSLT File: -

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/XXXX" exclude-
result-prefixes="t">  
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="//t:Setting[@name='EnableI18NTesting']">
<Setting name="EnableI18NTesting" value="False"></Setting>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input XML File: -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><ServiceConfiguration 
serviceName="AppService" osFamily="4" osVersion="*" schemaVersion="2015-
04.2.6"   
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/XXXX">
<Role name="AppServices">
<Instances count="1" />
<ConfigurationSettings>
<Setting name="EnableI18NTesting" value="True" />
</ConfigurationSettings>
</Role>
</ServiceConfiguration>
```

Output XML File: -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><ServiceConfiguration 
serviceName="AppService" osFamily="4" osVersion="*" schemaVersion="2015-
04.2.6" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/XXXX">
<Role name="AppServices">
<Instances count="1" />
<ConfigurationSettings>
<Setting name="EnableI18NTesting" value="False" xmlns="" />
</ConfigurationSettings>
</Role>
</ServiceConfiguration>
```

Comment: The golden rule here is to create your elements in the right namespace, and the namespace (xmlns) declarations will look after themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the namespace of the inserted element:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/XXXX"
                exclude-result-prefixes="t">
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="//t:Setting[@name='EnableI18NTesting']">
    <Setting name="EnableI18NTesting" value="False"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/XXXX"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can simplify that by using the namespace as the default one:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/XXXX"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/XXXX"
                exclude-result-prefixes="t">
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="//t:Setting[@name='EnableI18NTesting']">
    <Setting name="EnableI18NTesting" value="False"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The simplified version doesn't work for me but the first suggestion does. Also exclude-result-prefixes="tt" is not required

Comment: The simplified solution did not transform the setting i.e. EnableI18NTesting was not set to False

Comment: @NikhilPandey: Oh, my mistake. Should be fixed now.